# Association populate returns results even if an association is empty

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm struggling upon a problem related to Sails.js and Waterline associations. 
The database technology is **mongoDB** and I'm using the **sails-mongo** adapter.
I have a model User which has an association with a Role model. The association is of one-to-many type. The association is declared as follows:

```
/** -------------------------
* User.js
* ---------------------------
*/
{...}
role: {
  model: 'Role'
},
{...}


/** -------------------------
* Role.js
* ---------------------------
*/
{...}
users: {
  collection: 'Role',
  via: 'role'
},
{...}
```

When I make a query to retrieve all the users and I populate the role attribute, I have the role attribute populated with the first role inserted in the database even for those users that don't have any role associated.

Anyone had encountered this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Today I've tried to switch to a MySQL database and everything is ok. If I call a find populating associations if there are no associations collection attributes are empty. It seems a problem with the sails-mongo adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
role: {
  model: 'Role',
  defaultsTo: null
},
```

I also think it's sails-mongo bug.